# Extrude faces seems to move faces and extrude outer edges

Tags: extrude

If I have the situation shown in the first image and extrude the faces I get the second image.

It is extruding the outer edges and moving the faces. I want to extrude everything that is selected.

I guess I am missing something in the way I have selected the faces maybe?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hidden rules of Blender's operators can become so familiar that you don't notice them any more, and work round them / with them without noticing them. This is an example, for me, so it's interesting to have a look.

Trying to reduce it to the minimum case, Blender seems to use quite a simplistic rule to avoid the creation of internal faces when extruding regions, while still providing expected behavior when extruding simple, isolated shapes.

[image]

In this example, we start with two squares. One has a connected face extending one side.

- The pink and blue faces were extruded downwards in separate operations. The pink extrusion left a face behind, the blue one didn't. This suggests Blender's rule is to duplicate a region of faces only if none of the edges surrounding it are shared  by another face.
- Sure enough, the green faces were extruded in one operation. Still, the extrusion didn't leave a face behind, even in the isolated region. So the rule seems to be not to duplicate faces if any bounding edge of the *selection* is shared. (This applies even if you try setting the extrude to 'Individual Faces')

So it's not something funny you've done. Your best route to where you want to go is probably to select the *edges* on the outside perimeter of your base, <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> them downward, and <kbd>F</kbd> fill the bottom end. Or, work in one direction, from the bottom up,<kbd>I</kbd> insetting on the way.

Comment: Thank you. I extruded the edges but then had to use the knife tool to add back in the edges so its a bit of a pain. Selecting verts with F doesn't work as it does not create verts in existing edges that lie between the start and end vert you use F on (hope that makes sense.

Comment: Got you..I was making a suggestion without being clear about your intended result..